# gnu make -j8 not running things in parallel

Tags: c++, makefile, android-ndk, gnu-make

I'm running an Android NDK make file using `ndk-build` which is just normal gnu make that runs with the google makefile templates. I'm running it with `ndk-build -j8` and I can confirm that indeed the `make` command line runs with `-j8`
The compilation however proceeds to compile my source files one by one, never running `clang++` more that once at a time. This was not always like that. Just a few days ago I used the same exact scripts and it used all 8 cores and was much faster.
What can possibly make gnu make not respect `-j8` all of a sudden?
Is there a way to make gnu make produce any explanatory information about this? The various --debug options don't seem to talk about it.

Running from OSX 10.10.5, version of gnu make is 3.81

Update: If I do `ndk-build clean` before, the build I do immediately after does run on all 8 cores. Subsequent builds done a day after return to only use 1 core

Comment: I guess you have some weird dependency in your `Makefile`. We cannot answer your question before seen it. Perhaps some `-include`d files is putting some mess.

Comment: BTW, you really should upgrade your GNU `make` to 4.1 and/or use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) or `make --trace` to debug such issues ; try a  `make clean` and/or `make distclean`

Comment: Your question should be closed since doubly off-topic here: no code shown (you should show your `Makefile`) but asking for debugging it and more on topic on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, disagree with closing based on off-topic, make falls directly in the domain of stackoverflow. However, we do need code samples here.

Comment: Do subsequent builds run *immediately* after the first build run in parallel? Is the issue clean vs. non-clean builds? What is the output from adding `-d` to both runs? (It will be a **lot** of output.)

Comment: As others have said, there's no way to diagnose what's going on without code. However, I'd guess that there's no parallel compilation because you've introduced a new dependency chain that prevents it. It won't be obvious. ndk-build include files do some tricky stuff behind the scenes. This is consistent with a clean build showing parallel execution, but an incremental one not. Use your vcs to temporarily roll back the code repo to where you were a few days ago to verify. Then look at what you've coded since then. Something in that time period is responsible.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that `make` is actually `make` (use `which make` and `type make` to see whether there are wrapping scripts, functions or aliases involved).

This could be also be at play: [Communicating options to a s submake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html):

> The `-j` option is a special case (see [Parallel Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html#Parallel)). If you set it to some numeric value `N` and your operating system supports it (most any UNIX system will; others typically won’t), the parent make and all the sub-makes will communicate to ensure that there are only `N` jobs running at the same time between them all. Note that any job that is marked recursive (see Instead of Executing Recipes) doesn’t count against the total jobs (otherwise we could get `N` sub-makes running and have no slots left over for any real work!)

And relevant to you:

> If your operating system doesn’t support the above communication, then ***`-j 1` is always put into `MAKEFLAGS`*** instead of the value you specified. This is because if the `-j` option were passed down to sub-makes, you would get many more jobs running in parallel than you asked for. If you give `-j` with no numeric argument, meaning to run as many jobs as possible in parallel, this is passed down, since multiple infinities are no more than one.

Comment: There are no submakes, I'm seeing only a single make process

Comment: @shoosh to make sure it's not your `make`, create a dummy makefile that has a bunch of targets that merely `echo` statements and execute `make all --jobs=16`. See my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37734959/4784683)

Answer (score 1):

Just Guessing:

1. Search for a `.NOTPARALLEL` pseudo-target in your make files. It prevents gnu make from building in parallel.
2. Do you have `-l` set and is the load higher than that? Then make will not start more than one job at a time.
3. Are you sure, that there are indepedant things to build, while you rebuild? Of course, `make` will only parallelize tasks, it knows to be independant from each other

Answer (score 1):

The answers above have given the known links to issues regarding your question.

Without knowing more about your setup, I can only guess:

Perhaps, somehow, running your build script is affecting MAKEFLAGS.

You could try directly passing the number of jobs into the ndk-build script. Edit your ndk-build script like so:

`$GNUMAKE -j8 -f $YourProgramDir/.../build-local.mk "$@"`