# GNU make - how to simulate multiple simultaneous jobs

Tags: multithreading, makefile, gnu-make

I know that to allow `make` to be multithreaded, I use the command `make --jobs=X` where `X` is usually equal to number of cores (or twice that or whatever).

I am debugging a makefile - actually consists of many makefiles - to work with the `--jobs=X` option. Here's an example of why it currently doesn't:

```
T1:
  mkdir D1
  output_makefile.bat > ./D1/makefile
T2:
  cd D1
  make
```

Executing this with `--jobs=X` will lead to a race condition because `T1` is not specified as a dependency of `T2` and eventually `T2` will get built ahead of `T1`; most of the bugs I need to fix are of this variety.

If `X` in `--jobs=X` is greater than the number of ?logical or physical? cores, the number of jobs executed simultaneously will be capped at the number of ?logical or physical? cores.

My machine has 4 physical/8 logical cores but the build machine that will be running our builds will have as many as 64 cores.

So I'm concerned that just because my makefile (a) builds the final output correctly (b) runs without errors on my machine with `--jobs=4` does not mean it'll run correctly and without errors with `--jobs=64` on a 64-core machine.

**Is there a tool that will simulate `make` executing in an environment that has more cores than the physical machine?**

What about creating a virtual machine with 64 cores and run it on my 4-core machine; is that even allowed by VMPlayer?

### UPDATE 1

I realized that my understanding of `make` was incorrect: the number of [job slots](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html) `make` creates is equal to the `--jobs=N` argument and not the number of cores or threads my PC has.

However, this by itself doesn't necessarily mean that `make` will also *execute* those jobs in parallel *even if I have fewer cores than jobs* by using task-switching.

I need to confirm that ALL the jobs are being executed in parallel vs merely 'queued up' and waiting for the actively executing jobs to finish.

So I created a makefile with 16 targets - more than the num of threads or cores I have - and each recipe merely `echos` the name of the target a configurable number of times.

make.mk

```
all: 1 2 3 4 ... 14 15 16

<target X>:
    @loop_output.bat $@
```

loop_output.bat

```
@FOR /L %%G IN (1,1,2048) DO @echo (%1-%%G)
```

The output will be something like

```
(16-1)   <-- Job 16
(6-1400)
(12-334)
(1-1616) <-- Job 1
(4-1661)
(15-113)
(11-632)
(2-1557)
(10-485)
(7-1234)
(5-1530)
```

The format is `Job#X-Echo#Y`. The fact that I see `(1-1616)` *after* `(16-1)` means that `make` is indeed executing target `16` at the same time as target `1`.

The alternative is that `make` finishes jobs (1-#of cores/threads) and *then* takes another chunk of jobs equal to #num cores/threads but that's not what's happening.

Comment: Why not use Make's natural dependency-handling abilities to prevent the race conditions?

Comment: "the number of jobs executed simultaneously will be capped at the number of ?logical or physical? cores." There's no such guarantee, have you simply tried `-j64`/`--jobs=64` on your machine?

Comment: @Beta `make` can only handle dependencies that you tell it about. In the above example, it does NOT examine the recipes and infer that `T2` depends on `T1`. That kind of inference is provided by Electric-Cloud's Huddle and I'm using it and it's awesomeness. But it's not free.

Comment: *You* can examine the recipes, deduce the dependencies and add the prerequisites. Isn't that what "debugging a makefile" means?

Comment: @Beta and then I have to rigorously test it by somehow executing an arbitrary number of jobs simultaneously i.e. regardless of the number of cores I have. Which is what my question asks.

Comment: @user657267 yes you're correct; see my update.

Comment: What was your question in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my "UPDATE 1":

No special software or `make` tricks are required. Regardless of number of cores you have, `Make` will execute the jobs truly in parallel by spawning multiple processes and letting the OS multitask them just like any other process.

> Windows PITFALL #1: The version of Gnu Make available on SourceForge is 3.81 which does NOT have the ability to even execute using `--jobs`. You'll have to download ver 4.2 and build it.

>

> Windows PITFALL #2: `make 4.2` source will fail to build because of some header that VS2008 (and older) doesn't have. The fix is easy: you have to replace the invocation of the "symbol not found" with its macro equivalent; it should be obvious what I'm talking about when you try to build it. (I forgot what the missing symbol was).